# How can I make this function work without using a global variable on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data which is divided by 2 groups, I render the description of each element and add a title to each group. the thing is I can only do that with a global variable, which is not good. how can I solve this?

I already tried using let and setting a state.
I need this in react

```
//this is my global var
   var lastGroup;

//this is where I map the data and show it 

{this.state.settings.map((setting, idx) => (
            <div>
   ///here I call the getTitle function that add title to each group
                {this.getTitle( setting.alert_group)}
              <div>
                {this.state.showDescriptiveTitle=true}
                  <div className="settings">
                    <div className="alertType">{setting.description}</div> 
                    <div>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Switch
                        checked={setting.status}
                        id={idx} 
                        onChange={() => this.onChange(setting, idx)}
                        color="primary"/>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

          </div>

//here is my getTitle function that uses the global variable

getTitle( alert_group){

if(lastGroup !== alert_group){
  lastGroup=alert_group;
  if(alert_group=="D"){
    return( <h6 >Descriptive</h6>);
  }else{
    return(<h6 >Predictive</h6>)
  }    
}
}
```

This works just fine, but how can achieve this without using a global variable?

Comment: you could just split your settings array into the respective groups and map over them separately. You could also use a class property to track this (better than global var) `this.lastGroup = lastGroup`. Really depends on your use case and what this is ultimately trying to do

Comment: I need to do it with one map like this, the older versión had 2 maps like you suggested

Comment: You can just use a `this.lastGroup` variable so its tied to the class then. I wouldn't overthink it more than that.

Comment: that worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear what you're trying to achieve by not using a global variable, nor what didn't work about using `let` and `state`. These are the options I can think of:

- Use `const` or `let` instead of `var`, which will be block-scoped rather than global. In this case you'd have to be in the right scope to access it.
- Define `lastGroup` as a state property and use `setState()` to update it in `getTitle()`, and access it via this.state.lastGroup. I suspect this didn't work because you're running `getTitle()` in the render, which would cause an infinite loop (state change causes re-render, re-render causes state change). You would have to figure out some trigger for running `getTitle()` other than just on every render.
- If your React component is a class, you could define it as a class property (e.g. in the constructor create `this.lastGroup`) and access it via `this.lastGroup`

Comment: Read the OP's code more :). Its a form, there are groups of form elements with a title. and the global variable is outside of the component, (global). He's trying to cache / not render the title unless its moved to the next group. I would strongly recommend you remove the second bullet point as you may get downvotes for recommending state (even though you call out the infinite loop, its still written like a way to do it).

Comment: The start property give me an infinite loop thats why didnt work, and the let variable dont change the value when i assign the alert_group variable.